# MS Access: Use a listbox to select and import table from a different Access database

Tags: ms-access

I have a main Access db that exports certain tables to a different Access db (called Results_backup). I'd like to have a way to import one of those tables from Results_backup into the main db, other than expecting the user to go to External Data and so on.

Ideally I'd have a list box on my form that shows the user all of the tables in Results_backup that have "ETR" in the name. Then the user could select one of the tables in the list box, click a button, and import that table into the main db.

So far, I'm working from this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim AccObject as Access.AccessObject
For each accObject in CurrentData.AllTables
If accObject like "*ETR*" then
me.listobjects.additem "ETR: " & accobject.name
End if
Next
End Sub
```

This only brings in tables from the current database (CurrentData.AllTables). So is there a way to do this on a different database, not the active database?

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:
1. You can query it from system table

```
SELECT [name]
FROM msysObjects IN 'b:\Results_backup.mdb'
WHERE [name] Like '*ETR*' AND Type=1;
```

2. You can modify your sample code

   ```
   Private Sub Form_Load()
       Dim tdTable As TableDef
       Dim DB as Database
       Set DB = OpenDatabase("b:\Results_backup.mdb")
       For Each tdTable In DB.TableDefs
           If tdTable.Name like "*ETR*" then
               me.listobjects.additem "ETR: " & tdTable.Name
           End if
       Next
       ' clean up
       DB.close
       Set DB = nothing
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you. The first solution works perfectly well for me so I'm giving that a correct answer, but the second option isn't working for me---I keep getting a compile error (method or data member not found) on the DB.AllTables. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: @DrL sorry, there was error in second way. I've corrected it.